# Deleting a specific node from a linked list - python

Tags: python, linked-list

As an exercise I am trying to create my own linked list. I have created a node class and a linked list class. I have been able to create a constructor and a node adder method. I am having a lot of problems with my delete method though. Here is my code first:

```
class Node:

def __init__(self,value,next=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next = next

def getNext(self):
    return self.next

def getValue(self):
    return self.value

class LinkedList:

def __init__(self,node):
    self.node = node

def __str__(self):
    node = self.node
    s = "[Node " + str(node.getValue())
    if node.getNext() is None:
        return s + "]"
    while node.next is not None:
        s += ", Node " + str(node.next.value)
        node = node.next
    return s + "]"

def add(self,newNode):
    node = self.node
    while node.next is not None:
        node = node.next
    node.next = newNode

def delete(self,value):
    head = self.node
    if head.getValue() == value:
        return LinkedList(head.next)
    temp = head
    while temp.next is not None:
        if temp.next.getValue() == value:
            temp = temp.next.next
            temp.next = None
            return LinkedList(head)
        temp = temp.next
    return "Sorry node is not here!"
```

My delete function you give it a specific value that a node in the list may or may not have and then remove the node and return the list unless the node does not exist then it will return a message. I have the case where you are removing the head by just returning a constructor, although to be honest I am not a big fan of creating a new instance of the linked list. Removing a node from anywhere else does not work though as I test it by printing out the list and it shows no change to the linked list. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, instead of:

```
temp = temp.next.next
```

do:

```
temp.next = temp.next.next
return self
```

Comment: If you are returning self, then don't forget to fix the first case as well to be consistent (self.node = head.next; return self).

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you wanted general feedback but here's a few thoughts and my implementation.

I think its easier for usability if the user doesn't need to use the Node class. So the constructor/add/delete can just accept the value directly.  In any case I think its nicer to make the Node class nested inside LinkedList to give it context.

You said you wanted to avoid creating a new instance of LinkedList so I've written it without the need for that.

The delete function removes only the first occurrence of the value (note there can be multiple nodes with the same value)

Its a bit unusual that your delete function returns a message. I think its better to put this in an exception if you want an error message or if this is the only expected error maybe just return True or False.

I haven't written an iterator, clearly that would needed.

```
class LinkedList :

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, value) :
            self.__value = value
            self.next = None

        def getValue(self) :
            return self.__value

    def __init__(self, value) :
        self.__node = self.Node(value)

    def __str__(self) :
        if self.__node is None :
            return '[empty]'

        node = self.__node
        s = "[Node " + str(node.getValue())
        if node.next is None:
            return s + "]"
        while node.next is not None:
            s += ", Node " + str(node.next.getValue())
            node = node.next
        return s + "]"

    def add(self, value):
        if self.__node is None :
            self.__node = self.Node(value)
            return

        node = self.__node
        while node.next is not None :
            node = node.next
        node.next = self.Node(value)


    def delete(self, value) :
        if self.__node is None :
            return False # or maybe raise

        node = self.__node
        if node.getValue() == value :
            if node.next is not None :
                self.__node = node.next
            else :
                self.__node = None
            return True

        while node.next is not None :
            if node.next.getValue() == value :
                newNext = node.next.next
                if newNext is not None :
                    node.next = newNext
                else :
                    node.next = None
                return True
        return False # or maybe raise
```

Comment: That's a great implementation! Maybe for another data structure I will look into your implementation, I am trying to implement trees and graphs using python. I am a little weaker on the object-oriented side so I think this will help as well!